# How to validate the syntax in cron job

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel, cron

We are creating a new cron job under `/etc/cron.d`.

This cron job has around 56 lines, and all commands should be executed at the start of each month.

I am looking for suggestions to validate the syntax of the cron job.

I mean, how can I verify if the cron job file is configured correctly without mistakes - is there some command which can verify this?

Comment: if you have to have 56 lines in cron you might be doing something wrong. I would prefer to offload that to a script.

Comment: See [Is there a way to validate /etc/crontab’s format?](https://serverfault.com/questions/43733/is-there-a-way-to-validate-etc-crontab-s-format).

Comment: I second Rui’s comment. Beyond that, how much validation are you looking for? `crontab -e` will validate a crontab before installing it, but I’m not sure that’s easily accessible in other scenarios. It also only validates the cron-specific syntax, it doesn’t validate the command.

Comment: You have 56 entries in the new file, and just want to make sure they are configured to be run on the 1st of each month?

Comment: I mean I want to verify the syntax ,

Comment: Actually `crontab` in its default replacement mode will also validate the syntax of the crontab that’s provided, but that won’t work for `/etc/cron.d`-style files.

Comment: _I am looking for suggestions..._ makes rarely a good question on SE. Moreover, _how can I verify if the cron job file is configured correctly without mistakes_ - without a concise definition of _configured correctly_ and _without mistakes_ how should anyone give a sensible answer? I'm afraid there is no `do-what-I-mean` script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start to a validator, written in awk, that checks:

- for non-commented lines
- for lines with enough fields to look like a crontab entry
- where the day-of-month value in $3 is not 1 or *
- where the month value is not `*`

... then print the (offending) line.

On a sample input of:

```
53 23 * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A
53 23 1 * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A
53 23 2 * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A
```

The output is:

```
53 23 2 * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa2 -A
```

This would have to be enhanced to handle month names and ranges (or even `@monthly`), as the cron syntax allows.

```
awk '!/^#/ && NF >= 7 && ($3 != 1 && $3 != "*") && $4 != "*" 1'
```